# $\pi(X)\geq [\log_2(\log_2X)]+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\pi(X)$ be the prime counting function.I want to show that$\pi(X)\geq [\log_2(\log_2X)]+1$,where $[ $ $]$ denotes the greatest integer function.I am not able to figure out how to start the proof?Can someone guide me how to show this?

Comment: That is a very, very weak lower bound...much stronger bounds are known.  I understand that you are probably meant to establish this bound using the (elementary) techniques you have covered, but of course we have no idea what those techniques are.

Comment: That said, a typical starting point for elementary bounds on $\pi(x)$ is to remark that every integer can be written as a square times a square free number.  There are, of course, no more than $2^{\pi(x)}$ square free numbers less than $x$.

Comment: @lulu I am newcomer in number theory,can you please write the solution in detail in an answer because from what you said,I can't understand how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof can be adapted from the one found in Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*:

Let $p_1, \dots, p_n$ be distinct primes in order. We know $p_{n + 1} \leq p_1 \cdots p_n + 1$. Thus by induction,  we obtain $p_{k + 1} \leq 2^{2^k}$, for $p_{k + 1} \leq p_1 \cdots p_k + 1 \leq 2^{\sum_{0}^{k-1} 2^j} + 1 = 2^{2^k - 1} + 1\leq 2^{2^k}$, so that $\pi{(2^{2^k})} \geq k + 1$. Now choose $n$ such that $2^{2^n} \geq x \geq 2^{2^{n-1}}$. Then we have $\pi{(x)} \geq n$, which is the expression you wanted.

Comment: @GabrielCBarbosa why is $p_{n+1}\leq p_1...p_n+1$?